# Clicking on md-select creates unecessary "overflow-y: scroll;" to my <body>

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I usually have on my body:

```
element.style {
  -webkit-app-region: drag; 
}
```

but when I click on a [md-select](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.select) element (you can even see this behaviour on this link!) I get some new styles added.

```
element.style {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}
```

I tried to manually say to `overflow-y` be *hidden* but it gets overwrited. Does anyone have an idea how I can hide this scrolling bar?

Comment: Did you try with `!important`?

Comment: That solved the problem! Damn I feel dumb not thinking about this before. Thank you!

Comment: Just to update, this is fixed in Angular Material 0.10.1-rc1 and this hack will no longer be necessary once 0.10.1 is released.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `overflow-y` gets overwritten is because your custom css comes before whatever other CSS you are using. There is nothing wrong with using `!important`, but you should know *why* that solution is necessary so that you can prevent it in the future or even disregard using it all together by just putting your custom CSS after the other CSS you use.